# Android multi time button press problem?

Tags: android

i have very annoying scenario

on button click i show toast or start thread.

what problem i am facing right now is

user presses same button many times and there are lots of toasts and threads starts one by one 
i have seen some mobile apps after pressing button they disable touch screen

or any one guide me how to handle this situation in android? or how android developers deals with this problem?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For threads use the [AsncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and use [getStatus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29) to see if you need to fire the thread off again. For dialog boxes use [isShowing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing%28%29). For other tasks that expire on their own use a *long* to hold the time of the last start and only allow it start again if enough time has passed.

Comment: if i am not using asncTask and normal thread on button click then?